# How do I in code add new field values to a D8 content entity?

Tags: entities, 8

How do I in code, create a new field value, add it to a content entity, and then have it saved to the DB?

[Field API is dead. Long live Entity Field API!](https://amsterdam2014.drupal.org/session/field-api-dead-long-live-entity-field-api) clearly shows how to read values, but doesn't mention inserts/updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with "field value", do you mean field items with multiple values?

It's the same as reading them, nothing special:

```
// Those are identical, not specifying [0] results in that using by default.
$entity->some_field->value = 'Whatever';
$entity->some_field[0]->value = 'Whatever';

// To add a value for the second item:
$entity->some_field[1]->value = 'Something';

// And persist to DB:
$entity->save();
```

Edit, the following script works for me and gives me the following output:

```
<?php
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;

$node = Node::create(array('type' => 'article'));
$node->field_tags->target_id = 5;
var_dump($node->field_tags->getValue());

$node->field_tags[] = 6;
$node->field_tags[] = array('target_id' => 7);
var_dump($node->field_tags->getValue());

unset($node->field_tags[1]);
var_dump($node->field_tags->getValue());
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'target_id' =>
    int(5)
  }
}
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'target_id' =>
    int(5)
  }
  [1] =>
  array(1) {
    'target_id' =>
    int(6)
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    'target_id' =>
    int(7)
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'target_id' =>
    int(5)
  }
  [2] =>
  array(1) {
    'target_id' =>
    int(7)
  }
}
```

The delta is off then in the last example, but this will probably be fixed in https://www.drupal.org/node/2164601, which might also affect how the code above works..

Comment: I assumed that I needed to created an appropriate entity class instance of some kind? Some sort of extension of TypedData? FWIW, In my particular example I'm trying to add an entity reference.

Comment: If you have an entity that has a field then no, you do not have to do anything special. The only different for an entity reference is that you have something like ->target_id = 5; instead of ->value.

Comment: That seems too easy! ;) I'll try tomorrow, thank you very much. :)

Comment: It is easy. There is a lot of magic behind the scenes to make it look that easy, but that is not relevant for you.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a call to $entity->save(), which I needed to persist the change. I assume this is the correct way to do it. One minor question, this solves updating existing info, but what about "add another"? Should one do `$entity->$field[count($field)]->value`, or is there a shortcut for this?

Comment: $entity->$field[]->target_id = 5; should work I think. Did you try that ?

Comment: yeah, PHP doesn't like that approach as [] doesn't return anything. The specific error is: "Cannot use [] for reading".

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've ended up doing. In my examples, I'm adding and removing an entity reference.

How to add a new field value:

```
// Insert a new field value:
$field = 'field_name';
$fieldItems = $entity->$field->getValue();

$entity->$field->setValue(
  array_merge(
    $entity->$field->getValue(),
    array($target_entity)
  )
);
$entity->save();
```

I found no way of removing field items directly, so instead I overwrite all of them.

```
// Removing a field value. In this example, an entity reference.
foreach ($fieldItems as $delta => $fieldItem) {
  if ($fieldItem['target_id'] === $target_entity_id) {
    unset($fieldItems[$delta]);
    $entity->$field->setValue($fieldItems);
    $entity->save();
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: unset($entity->field_name[$delta)) works fine, you don't need to set the values again.

Comment: @Berdir I actually tried that, I couldn't get it to work. IIRC the $delta's weren't what I expected, which was the source of the problem. I'll try again and report back. :)

Comment: I added a working script that I tested in my answer.

Comment: I think we're supposed to set these to NULL as per [Set entity values to NULL instead of using unset() method: unset() is misleading](https://www.drupal.org/node/2418587).