# Avoid duplicate entries when programmatically adding field values

Tags: 8

This [pretty cool answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/135829/59357) taught me to push new term references like this:

```
$node->field_tags[] = 6;
```

... but if that reference already exists you get a duplicate.

This isn't possible through the UI and isn't what you would usually want. The duplicates show up in the rendered view.

Here's the horrible thing I did to check for the reference I'm trying to add:

```
$term_refs = $node->field_tags->getValue();    
$has_ref = count(array_filter($term_refs, function ($term_ref) use($tid) {
return in_array($tid, $term_ref);
  }));
if (!$has_ref) $node->field_tags[] = $tid;
```

Is there a **hasValue()** method or **magic PHP function** I'm missing that I can use instead?

The structure of `$term_refs` (the `field_tags` value) looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [target_id] => 6
        )

)
```

**Update:** Clive's solution is what I'm looking for but I couldn't get this to work. So I modified George's answer to this so I can skip existing refs:

```
if (in_array($tid, array_map(function ($i) { return $i['target_id']; }, $term_refs))) continue;
```

Comment: I think field classes implement `ArrayAccess`, would `if (!in_array($tid, $node->field_tags)) {` do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) could solve your problem here, perhaps employing a similar solution to the one proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10408482/how-to-get-unique-value-in-multidimensional-array